# Parsing complicated XML using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to parse an XML-formatted document with Jsoup, specifically what is located in the paragraph tag in the example code show below.

```java
...
<nitf:body.content>
     <p> Content would be here. </p>
</nitf:body.content>
...
```

There are multiple paragraph tags in the document. As a result, I chose to use selector-syntax to get inside the body.content tag and then the paragraph tag underneath it. I am trying and failing to get it right now with:

```java
// epochFileDoc is the name of the document with the code shown above.
Element tag_element = epochFileDoc.selectFirst("nitf|body.content > p");
```

I have tried a few different combinations of the selector syntax, including "nitf|content.body > p" and "nitf|body > p". None of the ones I have tried have worked.

How would I use selector-syntax in Jsoup to get the paragraph tag shown above?

EDIT: I see why content.body does not work in the selector syntax, since that searches for nitf:content="body" in the tags, but I'm still lost on how to get that element.

Comment: Can you use a different XML parser instead, e.g: one based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath rather than something that only supports CSS selectors? A dot has a special meaning in CSS.

Comment: I would follow that suggestion if I could; I am required to use Jsoup for this software. I created a workaround for this issue which I'll post in a second, since the dot has a special meaning (like you said).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is not possible to select using a CSS selector, like Jsoup uses, is because a dot has a special meaning in CSS (like @Shlomi Fish said).
In my code, I replaced instances of nitf:body.content with nitf:body-content using the line below, where file is the string where the XML is stored:

```
file = file.replace("<nitf:body.", "<nitf:body-");
```

This allowed me to select the Element using:

```
Element tag_element = epochFileDoc.selectFirst("nitf|body-content > p");
```

It would be smarter to use a different parser for XML-formatted code in cases like this, but if you have requirements like mine/want to keep Jsoup this workaround works properly.

Answer (score 1):

@dacmacho's explanation is correct and the workaround will do, if you can modify the data before parsing it.

There now is a less invasive solution: I've just pushed a pull request ( https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/1442 ) to JSoup, **enabling the use of escape backslashes within the selector** for element-names and CSS-identifiers.

So with that change, you'd simply use (note the backslash right before the dot):

```
Element tag_element = epochFileDoc.selectFirst("nitf|body\.content > p");
```